# Python 2.7 - Convert datetime with +01:00

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, datetime

So I have this string: '2018-02-06T12:12:29.98+01:00' which is a date. Ultimately I want to convert it back to a string containing this date: '2018-02-06 13:12:29'. So basically I just want to remove +01:00. To do this I guess I first need to convert the string to a date object like this:

```
import pytz
import dateutil.parser
tempdate = '2018-02-06T12:12:29.98+01:00'
test = dateutil.parser.parse(tempdate)
print(test) # --> 2018-02-06 12:12:29.980000+01:00
```

When I later try to convert this to the desired format and remove the +01:00 like this I get one hour back instead of one hour forward:

```
date = test.astimezone(pytz.utc)
print(date) # --> 2018-02-06 11:12:29.980000+00:00
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this? I am using python 2.7

Comment: If `test` is +1hr, shouldn't `date` be -1hr, i.e. we should see 11:12:29 ?

Comment: '2018-02-06T12:12:29.98+01:00' this means 12:12 in the local time which happens to be utc+1 (central europe). `test.astimezone(pytz.utc)` then converts this time to utc, which is 11:12. So are you sure you want to add an hour to your tempdate to get 13:12?

Comment: you want to keep the same time just change the tz?

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse
import pytz

date_str = '2018-02-06T12:12:29.98+01:00'
date = parse(date_str)
date = date.replace( tzinfo=pytz.utc )
print(date)
```

> 2018-02-06 12:12:29.980000+00:00

pytz to the rescue :-)

Comment: The desired and expected output should be 13:12 nåt 12:12

Comment: @danielo Then _„So basically I just want to remove +01:00.“_ in your question is a _bit_ misleading. ;-)

Comment: @danielo And _why_ do you want to _add_ an hour?